# Continuity property of sub-differentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, convex-analysis, subgradient, non-smooth-analysis

Assume that $g\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\left(-\infty,\infty\right]$ is continuous over its domain, convex, closed and proper.  For some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, assume that $x\in\partial g\left(y\right)$.  Also, suppose that there exists a sequence $\left\{x^k\right\}$ such that $x^k\to x$.

Can we say that there exists a sequence $z^k\in\partial g\left(x^k\right)$ such that $z^k\to y$? Are there any assumptions need to made on the function $g$ for this statement to be true? Should $g$ be LSC? Something else?

I encountered this problem while trying to prove convergence of an algorithm to a critical point. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking because of your notation. If $\xi_k \in \partial f(x_k)$, $x_k \to x$ and $\xi_k \to \xi$ then $\xi \in \partial f(x)$. This is because the map $x \mapsto \partial f(x)$ is upper semi continuous in a set valued sense (see, for example, Clarke, "Optimization and nonsmooth analysis", Proposition 2.1.5 (d)).

Comment: My question is about "the other direction" of the statement you mentioned. If $x^k\to x$ and $\xi\in\partial f\left(x \right)$, then can we say that there exists a sequence $\xi^k$ such that $\xi^k\to\xi$ and $\xi^k\in\partial f\left(x^k \right)$?

Comment: No, suppose $f(x) =I_{(-\infty,0]}(x)$ ($I_A$ is the 'convex' indicator function, that is, $0$ in $A$ and $+\infty$ outside). Then $\partial f(x) = \{0\}$ for $x < 0$ and $\partial f(0) = [0,\infty)$. So, with $x_n = -{1 \over n}$ and $\xi = 1 \in \partial f(0)$, then $\xi_n = 0$ and so cannot 'approach' $\xi$.

Comment: Yeah, this seems true. It means that I need to try and prove it for the particular sequences generated by the algorithm, as the general case is not true. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Actually, my example was unnecessarily involved, $f(x) = |x|$ would suffice. $0\in \partial f(0)$ but for $x \neq 0$, $|\xi| = 1$ for $\xi \in \partial f(x)$.